# How can I get my code to insert at cursor, instead of automatically appending at the end of the document

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a template builder Google Docs addon of sorts (which I have succeeded at) where it pulls in content from 1 document into the current one but my problem is that the way it's set up it appends each element pulled in, into the end of the document each time instead of at the cursor position and all my attempts at it have failed.

Here is the function that inserts the template part:

```
function insert() {

      var baseDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

    var body = baseDoc.getBody();

    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docID).getBody();

    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();

    for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
        var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
        var type = element.getType();
        if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
            body.appendParagraph(element);
        else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE)
            body.appendTable(element);
        else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM)
            body.appendListItem(element);
        else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE)
            body.appendImage(element);

        // add other element types as you want

        else
            throw new Error("According to the doc this type couldn't appear in the body: " + type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to insert the paragraphs, tables, lists and images in `otherBody` to the cursor position of the active Document.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your case, at first, please retrieve the cursor position of the active Document.
- `appendParagraph` appends the paragraph to the last body of Document. So in this case, please use `insertParagraph`.

  - And in this case, please set the position.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please put the cursor to the active Document and run the function `insert`. By this, the paragraphs, tables, lists and images in `otherBody` are inserted to the cursor position.

```
function insert() {
  var docID = "###";  // Please set the Document ID.

  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = baseDoc.getBody();
  var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docID).getBody();

  var cursor = baseDoc.getCursor();  // Added
  var cursorPos = baseDoc.getBody().getChildIndex(cursor.getElement());  // Added

  var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
  for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
    var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
      body.insertParagraph(cursorPos + j, element);  // Modified
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE)
      body.insertTable(cursorPos + j, element);  // Modified
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM)
      body.insertListItem(cursorPos + j, element);  // Modified
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE)
      body.insertImage(cursorPos + j, element);  // Modified
    else
      throw new Error("According to the doc this type couldn't appear in the body: " + type);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getCursor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getcursor)
- [insertParagraph()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-paragraph)
- [insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-table)
- [insertListItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertListItem(Integer,ListItem))
- [insertImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertimagechildindex,-image_1)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tasmto Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.